# Flutter refresh tabbarview on close dialog

Tags: flutter

I have two dart files. First dart file builds the tabs which calls the second dart file, StatefulWidget, with the content for each tab. In the second dart files there is a dialog which, after confirm, makes an API call. A Snackbar shows if the call was successful or not. All this works, except that the tab content is not refreshed once the API call is done and I don't know where to put the setState(). Navigator.pop(context) does not refresh the page, tab content, either.

From second dart file, in dialog:

```
actions: <Widget>[
  new FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
    child: new Text('CANCEL')),
  new FlatButton(
    onPressed: () async{
      await _postAction(action, linkId);
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
    child: new Text('I CONFIRM')),
]
```

From second dart file, API call:

```
Future _postAction(String action, String linkID) async {
  setSnackBar('Please wait, Action started...', 'Info');
  bool _actionResult = false;

  _actionResult = await PopWorkRepository().actionDetectPort(linkID, 'true');
  if (_actionResult) {
    setSnackBar('Action completed successfully.', 'Success');
  } else {
    setSnackBar('Action failed!', 'Error');
  }
// here should the tabcontent be refreshed
}

void setSnackBar(String msg, String status) {
  switch (status.toUpperCase()) {
    case 'INFO':
      snackBarColor = HexToColor('#399de7');
      break;
    case 'SUCCESS':
      snackBarColor = HexToColor('#3bb081');
      break;
    case 'FAILED':
    case 'ERROR':
      snackBarColor = HexToColor('#ff3a19');
      break;
  }
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text('$msg'), duration: new Duration(seconds: 2), backgroundColor: snackBarColor));
}
```

Any help, suggestion or link will be appreciated.

Comment: Please give your full widget code as what is setSnackBar

Comment: I have added the snackbar

Comment: If they are tow different widgets then context are different try passing context of first widget in this

Comment: Unless you're not showing relevant parts of code, it should be as simple as adding `.then((_) {setState(() {});});` after calling _postAction from the dialog.